# linux 'top' not showing all processes

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, top, qemu

I am running linux top command to see processes running inside qemu VM. Sometimes, a process does not appear in them, but if I run,

```
ps -eo psr,pcpu,comm | grep myprocessname
```

then the process is shown there. Also, such processes have low CPU utilization. Can you tell a reason of why it is so and whether it is due to the fact that processes are sleeping or something else. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Top only displays the most cpu heavy tasks, take a look at the documentation.

http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_top.htm

Comment: The link redirects to something else now :(